# How to fix string user input without using cin.ignore() and clear()-- C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, vector, input

Beginner programmer here, I am having issues with the string input 
structure of the program -- I am having trouble successfully storing the string 
user input for year, genre, and director. I tried not using cin >> with 
getline, and just use only get() and getline() -- but the error still persists 
with the string inputs not being stored properly. EX: If user enters choice 'B', 
and stores the year string input "2015" into string variable whatYear, it 
results in an error of not being stored properly. How to fix?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

void printYear();
void printGenre();
void printDirector();

using namespace std;

int main(){

char choice;
```

The user will enter a choice: 'B' for year, 'C' for genre, and 'D' for director.

```
cout << "Hello movie'goer, please select one of the following choices:\n\n"
 << "B - Display movies in a specific year\n"
 << "C - Display movies in a specific genre\n"
 << "D - Display movies from a specific director\n\n"
 << "Enter your choice: ";

choice = cin.get();

//Input validation
while (toupper(choice) != 'B' && toupper(choice) != 'C' &&
   toupper(choice) != 'D') {

cout << "Choice is invalid, the choice must be one of the following:'B',   'C', or"
     << " 'D'. Re-enter your choice: ";
 choice = cin.get();
}

cout << endl << endl;
```

This is where it processes the choice. 'B' will print the string year input, 'C' will print the string genre input, and 'D' will print the string director's name input.

```
switch(choice)
{
case 'a':
case 'A': break;
case 'b':
case 'B': printYear(); break;
case 'c':
case 'C': printGenre(); break;
case 'd':
case 'D': printDirector(); break;
}

}
```

When choice 'B' is inputted for year, I am having trouble storing the year input into the string variable whatYear.

```
void printYear()
{
string whatYear;
cout << "Enter a specific year: " << endl;
getline(cin, whatYear);
```

I checked to see if the string input was stored successfully, but it was a failure.

```
cout << "The input stored in string whatYear is: " << whatYear;
}
```

I am having the same problem here as well with the string input not being stored successfully into the string variable whatGenre.

```
 void printGenre()
{
string whatGenre;
cout << "Enter a specific genre: " << endl;
getline(cin, whatGenre);
```

The cout statement doesn't display it correctly here.

```
cout << "The input stored in string whatGenre is: " << whatGenre;
}
```

The same issue with the other two functions.

```
void printDirector()
{
string whatDirector;
cout << "Enter a specific director " << endl;
getline(cin, whatDirector);

cout << endl << "The input stored in string whatGenre is: " << whatDirector;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not using `operator>>` together with `getline()`, do not use `get()` with `getline()` either, for the same exact reasons. Just consistently use `getline()` to process interactive input, to avoid this kind of a mess.

When you used `get()` to read the menu choice, and entered "B" followed by , `get()` willingly consumed the "B" character, but the newline remained unread, which the subsequent `getline()` processed as an empty string, instead of processing the entered year.

Always, consistently, use `getline()` to read `std::cin` interactively.

Answer (score 1):

a possible explanation is that the `cin.get()` function reads only one character while you type two (the letter and enter).
the first one gets stored in `choice` while the second one is saved in the buffer and issues an empty line to your `getline()` call.

try cleaning the buffer before issuing the getline command with `fflush(stdin);`

even worse: some operating systems (MS windows - I'm looking at you) are using two character when you click enter: \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using get() with getline() was the issue. My issue have been resolved by replacing everything with getline(), and converting the get() to store menu choice as a char array to use cin.getline().
Thanks for the help all for those who answered, @Sam Varshavchik @kiwi

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow isn't meant as a help desk for resolving your personal issues, but as a FAQ like resource for future research. The issue you had was asked before many times, and one of the most upvoted Q&A pairs already contains the answer. Hence I marked your question as duplicate.